# Getting "AttributeError" while printing stopwords from nltk toolbox in python

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, stop-words

```
from nltk import stopwords 
print(stopwords.words('english'))
```

Second line is giving error which is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    print(stopwords.words('english'))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'words'
```

I have installed nltk using pip install nltk then i downloaded stopwords using command nltk.download('stopwords'), after unzipping that "stopwords" folder I placed that in python34/lib/site-packeges/nltk/stopwords

How can i get stopwords from this?

Comment: The module name is `nltk.corpus.stopwords` as shown in [the NLTK documentation](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html#wordlist-corpora). Try that instead.

Comment: You say "after unzipping that "stopwords" folder I placed that in python34/lib/site-packeges/nltk/stopwords".  Don't do that, put it where it belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, try

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

That should fix the error.